# KingswaySoft Replace Source Field with Destination

Tags: ssis, kingswaysoft

I am migrating data from our on prem system into our cloud system. The issue i have is that one of the fields and the GUID behind it doesn't match whats in the cloud and so the import fails. Is there a way of manually specifying the GUID/Name of the field in the upsert so that it uses that instead?

Thanks

Comment: Kind of vague, can you be more specific what you're looking to do? i.e. is it that row 1, field b is `DEADBEEF` and I need to translate that to `D00D2BAD` or the Customer endpoint locally is guid1 and in the cloud it's guid2.

Comment: Of course, sorry about that

Comment: Essentially, i am transferring data which includes the currency GUID, as the same one exists in the cloud but a different GUID. it won't let me transfer the data. What i need to do is look to replace the field for the currency GUID from the source with the one in the cloud

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a mapping between local guids and remote guids. `USD` is `DEADBEEF` locally and `D00D2BAD` in the remote system. If the systems allow for it, a Lookup Task matching on currency code should retrieve the remote GUID. Otherwise, fill out a table/spreadsheet and use that as the source in a "normal" lookup would be the easiest route. You would then have two guids in your data flow: CurrencyId and CurrencyId_Lookup (or some such naming convention) and in your destination editor, specify that we use the Lookup suffixed column

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update a lookup field in CRM using kingswaysoft, and u want to match the destination based on name field instead of GUID, try using text lookup feature in the connector. It would allow you to choose the target field name to match the input string. In this case If you are trying to update curency, then I recommend to use ISO currency code field.